# JSP send Java variables by ajax

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp

I want to send JSP java variables that I had defined via ajax request, it it possible?

My JSP :

```
<%
    String fileName = (String)request.getAttribute(MatafConstants.PARAM_IMG_FILE_NAMES);
%>
```

And then I want to send this String:

```
    $.ajax({
                  url: "/some/urlServlet",
                  type: "get", //send it through get method
                  data: { 
                    "statusID": status, 
                    "test": '<%=fileName%>' //here is the param I send
                  },
                  success: function(response) {
                    //Do Something
                    console.log(response);
                  },
                  error: function(xhr) {
                    //Do Something to handle error
                  }
 });
```

How can I sent this param? Or the bigger question I can I use JSP java variable in JavaScript?

Comment: What happens with your current approach?

Comment: do you want to keep your JS code on the same page with JSP?

Comment: Just saying, Ajax is using the Javascript, there is no JSP on the client side. This means that "fileName" is a constant at this point (that you output/write with the `<%= ...%>` tag. Check the source on the client, you will see that this will be like `"test": 'your parameter' //here is the param I send`

Comment: Well it works, but if the JSP variable I want to send is a Map?

Comment: You want to send the full Map with ajax ? If not, how are you choose the value you want ?

Comment: Yes, a full java map.

Comment: So what is the problem ? Once you have formatted the map to be able to be understood by the WebService call by the Ajax, there is no problem here

Comment: OK, I will try, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create hidden field with value from scriplet, and then use it's value in Java Script. Something like below:

JSP code

```
<input type="hidden" id="fileName" value="<%=(String)request.getAttribute(MatafConstants.PARAM_IMG_FILE_NAMES)%>">
```

Java script code

```
data: { 
    "statusID": status, 
    "test": document.getElementById("fileName").value;
},
```

Comment: And if it is an array?create each elemnent?

Comment: What type of elements do you have in array?

Comment: If that request only need to use that value, this could be done directly in the `data.test` field. There is nothing special about using an hidden field in this case

Comment: @AxelH yes, agree, now see comment to main question.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is YES. and your request looks correct. But make sure you add the AJAX call in the same page where that variable you are initiating.

```
<jsp:declaration>
    String name=null;
    String role=null;
    String company=null;
</jsp:declaration>
<jsp:scriptlet>
    if(request.getSession().getAttribute("username")==null){
        response.sendRedirect("../login.jsp");
    }
    else{
        name=(String)request.getSession().getAttribute("username");
        role= (String)request.getSession().getAttribute("role");
        company=(String)request.getSession().getAttribute("company");
    }
</jsp:scriptlet>
```

in javascript on the same page:

```
<script>
            var name="<jsp:expression>name</jsp:expression>";
            var company="<jsp:expression>company </jsp:expression>";
</script>
```